# How to setup a grunt file to compress only one CSS file

Tags: node.js, less, gruntjs

I am using **Grunt** and [grunt-contrib-less](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-less) to compile LESS files to CSS. Project has two CSS file but I want to **only one of them was minifier**. When I set "compress" above files are comressed.

Can you help me config Gruntfile.js?

my **Gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({
      less: {
         dist: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/main.min.css': [ // THIS FILE I WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/app.less'
               ],
               'assets/css/style.css': [ // THIS FILE I DO NOT WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/style.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: false
            }
         }
      },
   });

   // Load tasks  
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

   // Register tasks
   grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'less'
   ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create two seperate tasks. Something like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({
      less: {
         one: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/main.min.css': [ // THIS FILE I WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/app.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: true
            }
         },
         two: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/style.css': [ // THIS FILE I DO NOT WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/style.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: false
            }
         }
      },
   });

   // Load tasks  
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

   // Register tasks
   grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'less'
   ]);
};
```

**More info:** http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

**Edit:**

You'll need something like this then:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({
      less: {
         one: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/main.min.css': [ // THIS FILE I WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/app.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: true
            }
         },
         two: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/style.css': [ // THIS FILE I DO NOT WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/style.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: false
            }
         },
         three: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/main.min.css': [ // THIS FILE I WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/app.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: true
            }
         },
         four: {
            files: {
               'assets/css/style.css': [ // THIS FILE I DO NOT WANT TO COMPRESS
                  'assets/less/style.less'
               ]
            },
            options: {
               compress: false
            }
         }
      },
   });

   // Load tasks  
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

   // Register tasks
   grunt.registerTask('production', ['one', 'two']);
   grunt.registerTask('development', ['three', 'four']);
};
```

Comment: Your code works fine, but I need my "less:dist" because I need separate less:production and less:development, so when I use next level it stops working - check code here: http://pastebin.com/gPm9bHeL

Comment: Then you should make four seperate tasks. Two for production and two for development.

Comment: I've added an example above.

Comment: It is more complicated, because I use "[watch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch)" and now I still do not know how should I config my Grunt. Maybe look on full **Gruntfile.js** - http://pastebin.com/rW8tnywa - I checked line with problem. It is changed by me **Gruntfile.js** from [Roots](http://roots.io/) Theme WordPress.

Comment: When I start "_grunt dev_", **watch** will be starting **less:prod1** and **less:prod2**, so it is not good solution